# Kendo UI Menu from json object

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, wcf

I am having a problem creating a kendo menu with a json object returned from a WCF webservice.  The webservice call is working but binding to the control is not working?

here is my example code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

       var JsonMenu;

       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "cmService.svc/GetNavMenu",
           //data: JSON.stringify(params),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           processData: true,
           success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
               //  alert("success..." + data);
               JsonMenu = data;
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               alert(xhr.responseText);
           }
       });



       $("#menu").kendoMenu({
           dataSource: JsonMenu
       });

   })
```

```
<ul id="menu"> </ul>

</asp:Content>
```

and this is the object returned from the webservice.

```
[Object { text="BBC Home",  url="http://www.bbc.co.uk",  items=null}, Object {    text="BBC Sport",  url="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport",  items=null}]
```

when the page loads the menu is not created but if I step through with firebug the menu appears???  I am obviously doing something stupid but cant see it. I am fairly new to this as well so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I found what was wrong.

My control was initializing before I had got the data from the server.

corrected it by adding initialization into success event.

```
         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "cmService.svc/GetNavMenu",
           //data: JSON.stringify(params),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           processData: true,
           success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
               //  alert("success..." + data);

               $("#menu").kendoMenu({
                   dataSource: data

               })
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               alert(xhr.responseText);
           }
       })
```